# Get the real time passed on Android

Tags: android, time

I'm developing an application, which will have a custom yearly subscription license. I need to know exactly how much time has passed. The user could keep the device offline, therefore I can't check the time through internet. The user could turn back the clock, therefore I can't be sure of really passed time. Is there a way to get the real time elapsed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `System. nanoTime()`, which can help you measure an absolute elapsed time (as opposed to `System.currentMillis()` which will be adjusted if the system clock is changed).

See the [nanoTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) and [currentMillis](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) javadocs for more information.

ps: I have not tested it.

Comment: I can measure nanoTime() the elapsed time between two timestamp, but it has not a absolute reference, therefore I can't compare a timestamp of today, with that of another day, o after a device reboot.

Comment: `nanoTime()` gives time from last boot. So if user reboot the device it will start from zero

Answer (score 0):

you can have a preference or database that need to be stored the time when user install the application ... and you will always compare the time passed with the difference between stored time - current system time ........

or may be make a service to get network time

Comment: The current system time, can be changed by user, therefore it can't be used... To get the network time, need the device is connected to internet...

Comment: not the time from internet the device if connected or using any SIM then you can get the time from service provider .........

Comment: Yes, but my app generally will run on tablets, which are generally without sim...